# Windows software that emulates a hand draw in a custom card game

Tags: windows

I am looking for an app that supports the following:

- You can enter several cards with descriptions to form a user-defined deck
- Simulates shuffling the deck and drawing cards into a hand
- The ability to play player vs player in the same computer (i.e. Draw two or more hands from the same deck)
- Supports dice/tokens/etc

Emulation of field and gameplay is not required

Comment: Could you explain more what you mean by card descriptions? Maybe provide a simple example of what would constitute a good description. There are countless kinds of card games out there (UNO, Cards Against Humanity, Magic...). I don't think it's realistic for one program to emulate all that. This question is **too broad** with its current requirements

Comment: I am looking for it to support the random module and a deck. It should only emulate the hand rather than the field.

Comment: That makes more sense. I've edited the question to add that since it wasn't very clear. Feel free to edit it again and make it clearer

Comment: I find it still unclear whether we are speaking of a standard 52 cards in 4 suits of 13 deck or another type of deck.

Comment: @Mawg We are speaking of an deck of cards. It can be Yu-Gi-Oh, Magic the gathering, etc.